# Neo4j: db.schema() returns reflexive meta-relationships that do not exist in data

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I'm working on a Docker image of neo4j (`neo4j:3.5.3-enterprise`). When I run `call db.schema()` I get metagraph describing my data with several reflexive relations which are not in graph data.

For example in resulting metagraph I get:

```
(:Label1)-[:relation_type]->(:Label1)
```

There are no data with such a pattern, though. Indeed, if I run,

```
MATCH (n:Label1)-[r:relation_type]->(m:Label1) RETURN n,r,m
```

I get no data.

For what reasons could `call db.schema()` show that reflexive meta-relationship?